# Winforms Login phpMyAdmin and get HTML Source

Tags: c#, winforms

On the local network i have a similar page to this : http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master (here use: username = "root", pass = blank)

In a Winforms app i need to pass the login/password and get this HTML: http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master/server_status.php?db=&token=fda5205792a3caf29517c97c59ab1599

I'm looking for 3 days for a solution, but i can not get pass the login part.
This it the best i've got.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
        client.BaseAddress = @"http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master";
        var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
        loginData.Add("input_username", "root");
        //loginData.Add("password", "YourPassword");
        client.UploadValues(@"http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master", "POST", loginData);

        string htmlSource = client.DownloadString("http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master/server_status.php?db=&token=fda5205792a3caf29517c97c59ab1599");
        richTextBox1.Text = htmlSource;
    }
}
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get "input_username" from? Looking at the network traffic, the parameters you're looking for are called "pma_username" and "pma_password", along with some more...

Comment: I got it from inspect element. All u need is "root" username to login.   Tried with       loginData.Add("pma_username", "root");  and i get the same result.